# Use overrideUserInterfaceStyle on all active windows

Tags: swift, uiwindow, uiwindowscene, uiuserinterfacestyle

I have appearance settings in my app that look like that:

```swift
func changeInterfaceStyle(to mode: UIUserInterfaceStyle) {
    guard let window = view.window else { return }
    UIView.transition(with: window, duration: 0.5, options: .transitionCrossDissolve) {
        window.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = mode
    }
}
```

And obviously I want it to apply even if multiple instances of the app are open simultaneously on an iPad.
I've seen many things about `keyWindow`s, `UIWindowScene.connectedScene`, `.foregroundActive` here and there, but not some up-to-date, efficient and for multiple windows code.

So my question is simple, **what's the best way to loop over all active windows and efficiently override their interface style?** (btw my app is *iOS 14+*)

**EDIT 1:**
Ugly workaround:

```swift
UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.filter { $0 is UIWindowScene }.compactMap { ($0 as? UIWindowScene)?.windows as? [UIWindow] }.reduce([], +).filter { $0.isOpaque }.forEach { win in
    UIView.transition(with: win, duration: 0.5, options: .transitionCrossDissolve) {
        win.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = mode
    }
}
```